# access sql statement is returning nothing!

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba

i am having a problem with access sql SELECT statement. the problem is that when the backend is ACCESS-2007 it works; however when the backend is sql-server-2008, it is not returning anything. here is the statement:

```
SELECT IIf([Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)] Like '*1.11*Other*','1.11 Other',[Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)]) AS [Occurrence Code], Count([Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)]) AS [Count]
FROM [Lab Occurrence Form]
WHERE ((([Lab Occurrence Form].[Occurrence Date]) Between  Forms!Meeting_Reasons_Frequency!Text4  And  Forms!Meeting_Reasons_Frequency!Text2 )) And [Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)] Like '*1.*'
GROUP BY IIf([Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)] Like '*1.11*Other*','1.11 Other',[Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)])
HAVING ((Count([Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)]))<>0)
ORDER BY IIf([Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)] Like '*1.11*Other*','1.11 Other',[Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)])
```

please note that what is not working is this: `Forms!Meeting_Reasons_Frequency!Text4`  and this `Forms!Meeting_Reasons_Frequency!Text2` - when i replace those with constant values they work; however the trouble is that it they are not reading correctly what is in the textbox for some reason.

again: this query is working FINE with access as a backend, however when the backend switches to sql server it is not working! the reason again is because of the `forms!text` thing. does anyone know why?

**update**
thanks to bob's suggestion i ran profile on sql-server and found something funny. it is indeed working correctly, however it is returning the date like this:

```
@P1 datetime,@P2 datetime','2010-04-30 00:00:00','2010-04-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: IIF is Access specific, not SQL/TSQL

Comment: @omg ponies: this query is translated by access into sql/tsql. again, it works fine if i change those values to constants instead of getting them from the textbox

Comment: Can you capture the SQL statement that is run on the SQL server.  You should be able to use SQL Server Profiler.  The Access statement must be converted to the SQL Server version.

Comment: On a computer with SQL Server Client Tools, including the SQL Server computer itself, there will be a SQL Server Profiler program in the SQL Server path from Start menu.  Path may vary by SQL Server version.

Comment: @hansup i apologize to have deleted it in mid-answer! sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining your form control references as parameters:

```
  PARAMETERS [Forms]![Meeting_Reasons_Frequency]![Text4] DateTime, 
     [Forms]![Meeting_Reasons_Frequency]![Text2] DateTime;
  SELECT IIf([Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)] Like '*1.11*Other*','1.11 Other',[Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)]) AS [Occurrence Code], Count([Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)]) AS [Count]
  FROM [Lab Occurrence Form]
  WHERE ((([Lab Occurrence Form].[Occurrence Date]) Between  Forms!Meeting_Reasons_Frequency!Text4  And  Forms!Meeting_Reasons_Frequency!Text2 )) And [Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)] Like '*1.*'
  GROUP BY IIf([Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)] Like '*1.11*Other*','1.11 Other',[Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)])
  HAVING ((Count([Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)]))<>0)
  ORDER BY IIf([Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)] Like '*1.11*Other*','1.11 Other',[Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just jam the controls into your string.

```
Between  Forms!Meeting_Reasons_Frequency!Text4  
 And  Forms!Meeting_Reasons_Frequency!Text2
```

You need to separate them out and then look at your SQL string in the immediate window.

```
"<beginning query> Between " & Forms!Meeting_Reasons_Frequency!Text4 & _
" And " & Forms!Meeting_Reasons_Frequency!Text2 & " <rest of query>"
```

If you break on the creation of this string, you'll notice that the text box values will be displayed if you hover your mouse over the control name.

Comment: are you familiar with access sql?

Answer (score -2):

This is a shot in the dark but I think it is your LIKE's. Access uses *'s as the wildcards while SQL Server uses %'s. Even if the syntax is translated to t-sql, I wonder if it also changes *'s to %'s. Try it out...

Comment: @mario: the statement is working on sql server no problem, the problem is that it does not take data from my text control on my form thats all

Comment: Hmm, well I would have to look at your form.

Comment: @jenny: @Mario's answer may be correct.  If '*' is not replaced with '%', the the search pattern will be wrong and would return no results.  The '*' will be interpreted literally (There must be an asterisk in the column value to match).

Comment: @bobs: once more: the query IS working on sql server. however the form!text is not being pulled out of there

Comment: Access (Jet/ACE) indeed does supports the `%` wildcard character a) when in ANSI-92 Query Mode (see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-ansi-sql-query-mode-mdb-HP003070483.aspx) b) when you use the `ALIKE` keyword rather than `LIKE`.